# What is the correct syntax in metaprogramming assignment in Julia?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia, assignment-operator

I want x to take the value 4; why doesn't this work?  What would the correct syntax be?

```
x=3
y=5

z=[:x; :y]

:(z[1])=4
```

Comment: `eval( :( $(z[1]) = 4 ) )` will do what you want, but `eval` operates at global scope only, so using it is strongly discouraged in most circumstances. Dynamism is achieved by multiple dispatch, macros, proper datastructures, etc.

Comment: It most likely *won't* even do what you want, since it'll really only work as you expect at global scope (and not in any functions, where it can't touch local variables).

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps I should explain what I'm trying to achieve and hopefully you can tell me how I could get this done.   If I were to program in C then I could define z=[&x,&y] and set the values of x and y by doing something like *(z[1])=4.  Is there any way of accomplishing this in Julia inside a function?

Comment: int *z[2]={&x,&y} and *(z[0]) of course

Comment: Probably still x-y'ing here, but if you want to write to arbitrary memory addresses, see [unsafe_store!](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/c/#Base.unsafe_store!).

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah.  Julia is great in many ways, but I do miss the C-style #define and more flexible parallel computing....

Comment: Textual inclusion is very problematic in C. Macros should be able to do most/all of what you would need there. Definitely improvements yet to be made for parallel computing (the [discourse forum](http://discourse.julialang.org) is probably a better place for discussion of that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of `&x` in C++ in Julia, is to use a `Ref`.

```
x = Ref(1)
x[]     # get value of x, it's 1
x[] = 2 # set value of x to 2
```

What you want to do is

```
x = Ref(3)
y = Ref(5)
z = [x, y]
z[1][] = 4
```

For more information, see the section on [Ref](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/c.html#Core.Ref) in the documentation.